# Cursor giving NO_DATA_FOUND if column with empty value included

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a cursor defined as

```
CURSOR all_movie_nominations IS SELECT a.title, a.award_year,n.people_id FROM award a JOIN
                                nominee n ON
                                a.award_id = n.award_id
                                WHERE n.movie_id = (SELECT movie_id FROM movie WHERE movie_name = movieName);
```

The cursor is being opened and closed right.

Using the cursor in following code as

```
FETCH all_movie_nominations INTO award_title, award_year,nominee_people_id;
WHILE all_movie_nominations%FOUND LOOP

    SELECT given_name, family_name INTO first_name, last_name FROM people WHERE people_id=nominee_people_id;
    IF first_name = '' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The Movie was nominated for '||award_title||' for the year '||award_year);
    ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(first_name||' '||last_name||' was nominated for '||award_title||' for the year '||award_year);
    END IF;
    FETCH all_movie_nominations INTO award_title, award_year, nominee_people_id;
END LOOP;
```

Now the attribute `n.people_id` in cursor definition. This column contains empty values for some rows.

On executing the above code, I get the correct output but a 'NO_DATA_FOUND` Exception at the end of the output.

If I exclude the `n.people_id` from the cursor, I do not get any exception.

Any suggestions on what is possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what could be happen, I think that the not_found exception is thrown by the inner select sentence:

```
IF nominee_people_id is not null THEN

   SELECT given_name, family_name INTO first_name, last_name FROM people WHERE       
   people_id=nominee_people_id;

END IF;
```

I would try to put a condition that checks nominee_people_id is not null for executing the senetence.

I hope it was useful for you
Redgards

Comment: Thanks Alexis, That is exactly what was going wrong. 
I was just concentrating on cursor and not paying attention to SELECT.

Answer (score 3):

Unless this is student code about learning to use cursors, you would never code this way in real life. SQL statements inside a loop construct are a red flag. Because you are hammering the database this way with numerous (number of awards) tiny select statements retrieving a single person. Which means the PL/SQL engine has to switch to the SQL engine numerous times, leading to relatively expensive context switches. If you use joins, or in your case outer joins, you can minimize the number of context switches to one.

An example of an alternative (untested of course):

```
for r in
( select a.title
       , a.award_year
       , p.given_name
       , p.family_name
    from award
         inner join      nominee n on a.award_id = n.award_id
         left outer join people  p on n.people_id = p.people_id
   where n.movie_id = (select movie_id from movie where movie_name = movieName)
)
loop
  dbms_output.put_line
  ( case 
    when r.given_name is null then
      'The Movie'
    else
      r.given_name || ' ' || r.family_name
    end ||
    ' was nominated for ' || r.title || ' for the year ' || r.award_year
  );
end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Yes this is student code for learning purpose. 
Thanks for sharing the issue here. I will update my procedure accordingly. 
Cheers (y)

Comment: Also, I dint know we could do a `case` inside the `dbms_output.put_line` thats darn neat. Thanks

Comment: @MukulGoel - what you see in the answer above is a [CASE expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037), which is similar to but not quite the same as a [CASE statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm#i8305). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi you can opt for exception block for that if you want to ignore IF--END IF BLOCK;

BEGIN
SELECT given_name, family_name INTO first_name, last_name FROM people WHERE people_id=nominee_people_id;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
dbms_output.put_line('no data found for '||nominee_people_id);
END;
```

Comment: When the nominee_people_id is NULL that is not an EXCEPTIONAL case. That is totally a valid case. 

Anyway Thanks for your input. (Cheers)